# How to create a log file that logs the detail of each file copied in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logfile

I m developing an application that reads files from a remote server and copies it onto the local drive.

The code I m using to read and write the file is -

```
string saveTo1 = savePath + @"\" + filename[i];
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                using (Stream input = getResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (FileStream output = new FileStream(saveTo1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        int bytesRead;

                        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                        output.Close();
                    }
                }
```

How can I create a log file that keeps track of the details of file copy and also records if there is any error while copying the files?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, of course that you can create a log file. What would prevent you from doing so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84189/preferred-logging-infrastructure-for-net

Comment: @DarinDimitrov :D Thanks that was really motivational :p

Comment: @akhil, you asked if you can create a log file and I answered your question: yes, you can create a log file. So now I guess you will have to update your question and ask what you really need to know: `how do I do that?`. But when updating your question don't forget to provide what you have tried so far. Because Stack Overflow is not a rent-a-coder site.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I actually never asked for any code sir. I just wanted to know how can I do that. Sorry for not making myself clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log in different ways.

- EventLogger (as already suggested)
- Custom file log (as already
  answered)
- Log Engine: I suggest you
  [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). It's very powerfull
  and highly customizable.

Any way, I would shape the code in this way, where MyLogManager implement one of the previous solutions:

```
string saveTo1 = savePath + @"\" + filename[i];
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
try
{
            using (Stream input = getResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (FileStream output = new FileStream(saveTo1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    int bytesRead;

                    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    output.Close();
                }
            }
    //logging good news and info
    MyLogManager("Good news", FileDetails);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //logging bad news and exceptions info
    MyLogManager("Bad news", ExceptionDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly possible. Just create a file using the system.io file operations and for each file copied you open the log file and add a line. If you have an exception then rather than throwing it and breaking the application you can simply copy the exception details to the log file.

I would prefer to use this approach as you can tailor it to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many logging framework available on the net. I would suggest [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). Download and include it in ur Project.
You can do the following method,

```
try
{
        //Write your code here
        //OnSuccess : NLogger.Debug("file copied")

}
catch(Exception)
{
   NLogger.Error("Exception Details");
}
```

There are advantages using NLog which takes care of Archival, File handles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are desiring is a simple log. You can make it more useful.

Check here:

[.NET Logging Tools and Libraries](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/)